# Getting %0D%0D at the end of url while accessing from unix

Tags: windows, shell, svn, unix, tortoisesvn

I am accessing a file kept on my svn repository from unix by wget command.

```
#!/bin/bash 
 ANTBUILDFILE=http://l09089r4.tst.poles.com:1808/svn/CommonMDM/trunk/Common/BuildArtifacts/VendorCatalog_Weblogic/build_CustomUI.xml


cd /tmp/install

wget -nc ${ANTBUILDFILE}
```

But I am getting the output as :
    --2013-05-16 00:21:51--          http://l09089r4.tst.poles.com:1808/svn/CommonMDM/trunk/Common/BuildArtifacts/VendorCatalog_Weblogic/build_CustomUI.xml%0D%0D
    wget: /home/tkmd999/.netrc:3: unknown token "ibm"
    Resolving l09089r4.tst.poles.com... 10.8.91.58
    Connecting to l09089r4.tst.poles.com|10.8.91.58|:18080... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
    2013-05-16 00:21:51 ERROR 404: Not Found.

There are %0D%0D art the end of the url which is making it in accessible.

Post getting this error I have converted the file in question in url in unix format too, and commited my changes in the svn repositiry, bu still getting this error.

Any other ideas which I can follow to get rid of this error?>

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%0D` you see are most likely remains of Windows-style CrLf [Newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) in your shell script - one from the `ANTBUILDFILE=...` line, one from the `wget ...` line.

There can be a number of more or less subtle reasons for this, for example the [svn:eol-style](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.properties.html) property:

TortoiseSVN sets `svn:eol-style native` style by default, trying to follow the convention of the client OS.

This can lead to confusion when using network shares accessible by several operating systems or tools that have different expectations on newlines.

If this turns out to be the situation you are experiencing, you can simply remove the `svn:eol-style` property from the file and commit it with the newline style you want.

Comment: But how come svn:eol-style going to add the newline window character at the end of the url? I am not sure, but doesn't this property has to do with the end line characters inside of the file?

And I have double checked the path given in the variable, there isn't any spaces present at the end of the url path.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried inspecting a hex dump of your script? Try to run `hexdump -C your-script.sh` and look for `0d` bytes.